# splash screen take more than 15 second in android device using ionic 2 angular 2

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic2

i add splash screen it's work fine in iOS but take more time in android device.this is my config.xml preference

```
 <preference name="SplashMaintainAspectRatio" value="true" />
    <preference name="FadeSplashScreenDuration" value="300" />
    <preference name="SplashShowOnlyFirstTime" value="false" />
    <preference name="SplashScreen" value="screen" />
   <preference name="SplashScreenDelay" value="3000" />
```

my component.ts file is

```
import { SplashScreen } from '@ionic-native/splash-screen';
constructor(public platform: Platform,
              public Alert : AlertController, 
              public statusBar: StatusBar, 
              public splashScreen: SplashScreen,
              public keyboard : Keyboard
              ) {
                   this.initializeApp();
                }

initializeApp() {
    this.platform.ready().then(() => {

      this.statusBar.styleDefault();
       this.splashScreen.hide();
      this.keyboard.hideKeyboardAccessoryBar(false);
      this.keyboard.disableScroll(true);
    });
  }
```

Comment: are you hiding it with `Splashscreen.hide();`? Please also add the content of your `app.component` file to see what's going on before hiding the splash screen...

Comment: @sebaferreras i hide the splash screen in app.component .

Comment: Ok, and do you do a lot of things before hiding it in the `app.component` file?

Comment: @sebaferreras i add all the thing that required in app.component file.

Comment: I'm sorry but I can't help if don't see the content of the `app.component` file to see if something that may take a long time it's being executed before hiding it.

Comment: @sebaferreras i edit my answer and add app.component file.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/145679/discussion-between-jatin-devani-and-sebaferreras).

Comment: after generation of signed apk, splashscreen loading time reduces

Answer (score 0):

Add the `--prod` flag during any of the following CLI commands

```
ionic emulate android --prod
ionic build android --prod
ionic run android --prod
```